# How does "not something we can merge" arise?

Tags: git, git-merge

This is a new one to me. I'm a fairly experienced user of git, and have just added a remote to a repo that was forked from mine, fetched the updates and then tried to merge them in:

```
$ git merge HEAD f6ff240dbf47234249a68b34c8a98bb11237aa7
fatal: f6ff240dbf47234249a68b34c8a98bb11237aa7 - not something we can merge
```

There is next to nothing on the web about this error message, which shocks me.  The nearest thing I can find is [this page about being in a detached head state](http://micharg.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/git-troubleshooting-fatal-branch-not.html). But `git status` reports that I am on branch master.

You can see the repositories I am trying to use on github - [my repo](https://github.com/aptivate/dye) and the [remote I want to pull from](https://github.com/qris/ping-dye). At the time of writing, master of my repo is at [6dc048862a93ffba6cd37883fd43e40651f248c1](https://github.com/aptivate/dye/commit/6dc048862a93ffba6cd37883fd43e40651f248c1).

Looking at the history I can see where the forks diverge, and I am trying to merge a commit from 3 commits up the fork. It doesn't seem that hard.

To replicate for yourself you could do:

```
git clone https://github.com/aptivate/dye
cd dye
git remote add qris git://github.com/qris/ping-dye.git
git fetch qris
git checkout master
git merge f6ff240dbf47234249a68b34c8a98bb11237aa7
```

Comment: In my case, the message is a usual `fatal: 'f6ff240dbf47234249a68b34c8a98bb11237aa7' does not point to a commit`

Comment: Different client versions? I got `not something we can merge` too. I use 1.7.10

Comment: I'm on 1.7.10.4 and got the message above. @bereal 's message would have been more useful.

Comment: Ah, that explains it, I'm on 1.7.9.5.

Comment: Thanks, similar problem arose for me when using pull request on bitbucket, they suggest that the user run a command like: `git merge --no-ff -m 'Merged in hotfix (pull request #1)' remotes/username/project/hotfix` but locally `remotes/username/project/hotfix` doesn't exist and you need to edit it to be `origin/hotfix`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's quite simple: `f6ff240dbf47234249a68b34c8a98bb11237aa7`  doesn't exist.

I just realize you mean `3f6ff240dbf47234249a68b34c8a98bb11237aa7` (Note the missing `3` at the beginning) Just go to the commit list and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> `f6ff`.

If that is someone you know, you should tell them to *always* branch from `master` and commit their custom changes there (for every change), instead of committing directly into `master`. Then he doesn't need to rebase and force-push the changes from upstream (you) and you only have to merge the specific story-branches.

Comment: Just checked and you're right - some how I missed the 3 off the front of the commit ID. D'oh. Still not the most helpful error message. Maybe your answer will help some future idiot like me ;) Thank you.

Comment: This might sound stupid but I got this error cause the branch I was attempting to merge TO did not exist. I had previously deleted it and simply forgotten.

Comment: In my case, it was a branch name and the solution to prefix it with `origin/` because it was a remote branch that I hadn't locally in my working copy.

Answer (score 3):

I got a same error message. In my case, the reason is I use '**(**' and '**)**' in branch name.

Answer (score 3):

I get the error if I use the wrong quotes (`HEX UTF-8 bytes  E2 80 9C` and `HEX UTF-8 bytes  E2 80 9D`) instead of the simple quote (`HEX UTF-8 bytes 22`) to enclose the commit message, see below.

```
Master@HP-ENVY-L MINGW64 ~/desktop/learning/git-practice/p_2 (master)
$ git merge feature-branch -m “Merge feature-branch into master”
merge: into - not something we can merge

Master@HP-ENVY-L MINGW64 ~/desktop/learning/git-practice/p_2 (master)
$ git merge feature-branch -m "Merge feature-branch into master"
Already up-to-date.
```

It happened because I copied and pasted the command from instructions instead of typing it in myself. The message git provides is rather unspecific.