# How to resolve git's "not something we can merge" error

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I just encountered a problem when merging a branch into master in git. First, I got the branch name by running `git ls-remote`. Let's call that branch "branch-name". I then ran `git merge branch-name` command and got the following result:

```
fatal: branch-name - not something we can merge
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: The only thing at worked for me was using command line auto-complete. I typed git and auto-completed merge and branch-name. Even copy pasting the branch name failed so it's possible there were hidden characters and this got rid of them. I'm on bash 4.4 and not sure if this works with all shells. Auto-completing git commands is a new thing to me.

Comment: In my case - they decided to change the name of  remote branch to `main` instead of `master`. It's great that they're trying to be BLM conscious, except it confused me massively.

Answer (score 597, accepted):

As shown in [How does "not something we can merge" arise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388625/how-does-not-something-we-can-merge-arise), this error can arise from a typo in the branch name because you are trying to pull a branch that doesn't exist.

If that is not the problem (as in my case), it is likely that you don't have a local copy of the branch that you want to merge. Git requires local knowledge of both branches in order to merge those branches. You can resolve this by checking out the branch to merge and then going back to the branch you want to merge into.

```
git checkout branch-name
git checkout master
git merge branch-name
```

This should work, but if you receive an error saying

```
error: pathspec 'remote-name/branch-name' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

you need to fetch the remote (probably, but not necessarily, "origin") before checking out the branch:

```
git fetch remote-name
```

Comment: This happened to me after adding a new remote - I needed to do a `git fetch` first before merging the remote branch in.

Comment: fetching and checkout out branch from remote. git fetch && git checkout BranchName

Comment: This happened to me when I was cd'd into the wrong project (i.e. it was a different repo that didn't even have the branch I wanted to merge)

Comment: If you're trying to sync a fork at the command line (https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/) this error is probably because you missed step 0. What? There's no step 0 listed? Yes, that's why it's easy to miss. "Before you can sync your fork with an upstream repository, you must configure a remote that points to the upstream repository in Git." <-- that is step 0. If you skip that step you get the above error, which you probably put into Google, leading you here. :-)

Comment: In my case I had a branch name `v1.0(1)` and changing it to `v1.0-1` resolved the error.

Comment: `Git requires local knowledge of both branches in order to merge those branches`

Comment: Worked for me (i have cloned from repository)

Comment: This occurred when I fetched but **did not checkout** the desired branch.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I didn't have a local version of my remote branch.

Comment: I was trying to merge a branch with name in lowercase (the real name was in uppercase) and got 
merge: origin/branch_name - not something we can merge

Comment: I was using the wrong casing

Comment: Simply you can use `git branch` to list branches after that you can use `git merge BRANCH_NAME`

Answer (score 167):

It's a silly suggestion, but make sure there is no typo in the branch name!

Comment: not so silly, as "typo" could reduce to the fact that the branch hasn't been fetched yet (and thereby unknown locally) .. Git does things differently than CVS or SVN ..

Comment: The problem could also be caused if the branch name contains characters like commas (,) or apostrophes (').

Comment: Also make sure you are in the correct repo or terminal window/tab especially if you work on multiple repos simultaneously.

Comment: this happened to me with uneven master/main renaming across forks!

Comment: Definitely make sure you do not have a typo in your branch name! Thanks @endless !

Comment: what a silly error message!

Comment: I was getting this error because I was typing, "master" instead of "main"

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I come back to your comment to realize this regularly at least 1x 3 months :-)

Answer (score 105):

When pulling from a remote upstream, `git fetch --all` did the trick for me:

```
git remote add upstream [url to the original repo]
git checkout [branch to be updated]
git fetch --all
git merge upstream/[branch to be updated]
```

In other cases, I found the "Not something we can merge" error will also happen if the remote (origin, upstream) branch does not exist. This might seem obvious, but you might find yourself doing `git merge origin/develop` on a repo that only has `master`.

Comment: I seriously don't know why this answer has not garnered as many votes as the above one. 'git fetch -all' is the command that one typically misses to run before merging a remote branch and that solved the problem for me.

Comment: Because fetch does not pull automatically and you have to do this manually. So a pair fetch --all & pull --all will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you! The `git remote add upstream` was the important thing I was missing that solved it for me. I think a common mistake is assuming a fork automatically knows where it was forked from.

Answer (score 39):

I had this issue as well. The branch looked like 'username/master' which seemed to confuse git as it looked like a remote address I defined. For me using this

```
git merge origin/username/master
```

worked perfectly fine.

Comment: I had to put `origin/` before the name of the remote branch too.

Comment: You'll have to do this if the branch's name has a forward slash `/` in it.

Answer (score 33):

The below method works for me every time.

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout branch-name-to-be-merged
git pull
git checkout branch-name
git pull
git merge branch-name-to-be-merged
```

Comment: This worked for me thank you.  I this is essentially the right solution: basically make sure you have the source branch checked out before trying to merge it in.

Comment: This worked for me, but not sure why? Can you explain?

Answer (score 16):

It may happen because that branch is not on your local. before merging use

```
git fetch origin
```

Answer (score 16):

This answer is not related to the above question, but I faced a similar issue, and maybe this will be useful to someone. I am trying to merge my feature branch to master like below:

```
$ git merge fix-load
```

for this got the following error message:

> merge: fix-load - not something we can merge

I looked into above all solutions, but not none of the worked.

Finally, I realized the issue cause is a spelling mistake on my branch name (actually, the merge branch name is `fix-loads`).

Comment: For me, adding origin worked. Taking your example, `git merge origin/fix-loads` worked.

Answer (score 10):

You might also encounter this error if you are not using `origin` keyword and the branch isn't one of your own.

```
git checkout <to-branch> 
git merge origin/<from-branch>
```

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue today when I was merging another branch into mine after directly pulling from master, I had to checkout and pull the branch I was merging first, then I could merge this branch into mine successfully.

```
git checkout branch-to-merge
git pull
git checkout my-branch-name
git merge branch-to-merge
```

Answer (score 8):

You are getting this error because the branch you want to merge doesn't exist on your local repository.

So, first checkout the brach you want to merge into master branch by the following command:

```
git checkout branch_name_to_merge
```

After this try to merge it with master branch by the following command:

```
git merge branch_name_to_merge
```

Comment: This can also happen if you aren't paying attention to the name of your branch (i.e. misspelled) :)

Comment: This worked for me.  When I am working in Atom with the Git tab and I switch branches with the drop down, sometimes I have to go to the command line and `checkout` the branch

Answer (score 7):

This error suggest that the branch from where you want to merge changes (i.e. in you case branch-name) is not present in you local, so you should checkout the branch and fetch the local changes.
Checkout to your master branch and fetch, then follow the below steps:

```
git checkout branch-name
git pull
git checkout new-branch-name
git merge branch-name
```

Comment: I will be picky and say I don't think the error message *suggests* anything like the above :-)

Answer (score 5):

I must suggest to check all branches or the branch you are looking for is available at first

`git branch -r`

check from the list

```
origin/HEAD -> origin/main
origin/feature/branch_1
origin/feature/branch_2
origin/feature/branch_3
origin/feature/branch_4
origin/feature/your branch
```

Suggestion is to copy the listing from origin itself then do `git merge origin/feature/branch_2`. Copy pasting will remove typo error.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when I did a `git merge BRANCH_NAME "some commit message"` - I'd forgotten to add the -m flag for the commit message, so it thought that the branch name included the comment.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion i had missed to map my local branch with remote repo. i did below and it worked fine.

```
git checkout master
git remote add origin https://github.com/yourrepo/project.git
git push -u origin master
git pull
git merge myBranch1FromMain
```

Answer (score 2):

If the string containing the reference is produced by another Git command (or any other shell command for that matter), make sure that it doesn't contain a return carriage at the end. You will have to strip it before passing the string to "git merge".

Note that it's pretty obvious when this happens, because the error message in on 2 lines:

```
merge: 26d8e04b29925ea5b59cb50501ab5a14dd35f0f9
 - not something we can merge
```

Comment: Please provide a comment when you downvoted an answer. Maybe it was not the issue the original poster had, but it's a possible cause of the error message (I had the problem myself).

Answer (score 2):

We got this error because we had a comma (,) in the branch name. We deleted the local branch, then re-checked it under a new name without the comma. We were able to merge it successfully.

Comment: Underscore also seems problematic. +1

Comment: I use underscores often in branch names @AndersLindén

Comment: and parenthesis was problematic too ...+1

Answer (score 2):

In My case, the Problem was in Branch Name. My new branch name contains brackets, Once I renamed it and remove brackets, It's sorted.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is late to answer but I also faced the same issue so I ran following commands

```
git checkout master
```

and then

```
git pull origin branch-name
```

It solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

to avoid typo error you can do

```
git fetch --all -v
```

then copy the name of your branch and do

```
git checkout <branch-name>
git checkout master
git merge <branch-name>
```

Answer (score 1):

For posterity: Like AxeEffect said... if you have no typos check to see if you have ridiculous characters in your local branch name, like commas or apostrophes. Exactly that happened to me just now.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking if you are able to switch to the branch that you are trying to merge with.

I got this error even though the branch I wanted to merge with was in local repository and there were no spelling errors.

I ignored my local changes so that I could switch to the branch (Stash or commit can also be preferred). After this I switched back to the initial branch, and the merge was successful.

Answer (score 1):

The branch which you are tryin to merge may not be identified by you git at present
so perform 
`git branch`
 and see if the branch which you want to merge exists are not, if not then perform 
`git pull` 
and now if you do `git branch`, the branch will be visible now, 
and now you perform `git merge <BranchName>`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I fixed it using the command below:

```
git checkout main
git fetch
git checkout branch_name
git fetch
git checkout main
git fetch
git merge branch_name
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was trying to execute git commands from a sub-directory of the git repository.
Please make sure its the directory you initialized with git and not its sub-directory.

Comment: Same here. My terminal was in a sibling directory in a multi-repo project.

Answer (score 1):

**My goal is to merge Branch2 code into Branch1**.

I got the below message while merging.

My branches Branch1 and Branch2. Please avail these branches in your project folder.

Initially i have only **Branch1** with **maser**, in this case i got the below mentioned message.

[image]

Now I have checked out into Branch2.

Now **Branch1**, **Brnach2** and **master** all are available in my project folder.

Now the merging steps are begin:

1. git checkout Brnach1
2. git merge Branch2

Finally we merged **Brnach2** with **Branch1**

Answer (score 1):

There can be many reasons for the same:

```
git merge dependabot/npm_and_yarn/storybook/addon-essentials-6.4.19
merge: dependabot/npm_and_yarn/storybook/addon-essentials-6.4.19 - not something we can merge
```

1. You are having a branch name with special characters.(as in my case):
   Solution: Checkout a new branch with easy name from the branch which is not able to merge. That could help.

```
git checkout -b feature-addon
git checkout dev
git merge feature-addon
```

2. This error can arise from a typo in the branch name because you are trying to pull a branch that doesn't exist.
3. Very silly but it is likely that you don't have a local copy of the branch that you want to merge.. Try `git fetch` to get it

Answer (score 1):

If you are following old tutorials, insted of `master` check if the branch is named `main` or something similar.

The error is telling you that `branch-name` must be the name of one of your branches.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem occured when I tried this:

```
git merge -s ours --no-commit --allow-unrelated-histories <remote name>/develop
```

So actually I should have written `master` instead of `develop`,because master was the branch name of Subtree,not my actual branch.

Answer (score 0):

This may sounds weird, but remember to setup your git email and name:

```
git config --global user.email "MY@EMAIL.COM"
git config --global user.name "FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was the 'double quotation marks' into merge message. So when I removed the double mark, all magically worked. I hope to help someone. (Sorry for my poor English)

Answer (score 0):

I had a work tree with master and an another branch checked out in two different work folders.

```
PS C:\rhipheusADO\Build> git worktree list
C:/rhipheusADO/Build         7d32e6e [vyas-cr-core]
C:/rhipheusADO/Build-master  91d418c [master]

PS C:\rhipheusADO\Build> cd ..\Build-master\

PS C:\rhipheusADO\Build-master> git merge 7d32e6e #Or any other intermediary commits
Updating 91d418c..7d32e6e
Fast-forward
 Pipeline/CR-MultiPool/azure-pipelines-auc.yml | 5 +++--
 1 file changed, 3 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)

PS C:\rhipheusADO\Build-master> git ls-remote
From https://myorg.visualstudio.com/HelloWorldApp/_git/Build
53060bac18f9d4e7c619e5170c436e6049b63f25        HEAD
7d32e6ec76d5a5271caebc2555d5a3a84b703954        refs/heads/vyas-cr-core 

PS C:\rhipheusADO\Build-master> git merge 7d32e6ec76d5a5271caebc2555d5a3a84b703954
Already up-to-date

PS C:\rhipheusADO\Build>  git push
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://myorg.visualstudio.com/HelloWorldApp/_git/Build
   91d418c..7d32e6e  master -> master
```

If you need to just merge the latest commit:

```
git merge origin/vyas-cr-core 
git push
```

And is same as what I've always done:

```
git checkout master # This is needed if you're not using worktrees
git pull origin vyas-cr-core
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

`git rebase the-branch-to-be-merged`

I solved the problem using this git command, but `rebase` is **only suited for some cases**.

Comment: I would avoid rebasing, it seems very extreme in my opinion for this basic branch merge error.

Answer (score 0):

Weird as it may sound, restarting my computer help solve the issue. I was using terminal from IntelliJ IDEA and autocomplete for the branch names, so I'm pretty confident it was not a typo error on the branch name.