# Understanding Branching with Git and Github

Tags: git, github, branch, git-merge

I have an issue. I have 2 branches, which are `master` and `my-destinations`. I made some changes on `my-destinations` branch that are not on `master`. I committed and pushed the changes onto my git repo from the `my-destinations` branch.

When I switch back to master the changes I committed and pushed onto the repo are not there, which I expected. However, when I switch back to `master` and run a `git status` it says that `master` is up to date. I would have thought that it would have said that `master` is one commit behind `origin`.

Can someone help me understand why `master` is up to date with `origin/master`, but does not have the committed changes?

Comment: You never merged the changes into `master` so why would it be behind? You'd need to `git checkout master && git merge my-destinations` for the changes to be in `master`

Comment: When I try git merge git responds with "not something we can merge" what is this response referring to?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862933/how-to-resolve-gits-not-something-we-can-merge-error

Comment: Awesome thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone help me understand why master is up to date with origin/master, but does not have the committed changes?

Your `local master` branch has the same files than `github remote master` branch. That is why your (local) master branch is not behind your (remote) master branch.

Your (local) master branch would be behind (any amount of commits) if someone else (or you from any other remote computer) had commited new changes into the (remote) master branch.

Answer (score 1):

You added commits to `my-destinations`, in your local repo, not to `master`:

```
a              <-- master ref is (a)
 \
  b - c - d    <-- my-destinations ref is (d)
```

When you pushed to `origin`, the remote repo, it simply took your existing local `master` branch, and made the remote repo `master` to be the same.  In other words, the remote `master` was updated to reference (a), just like your local `master`. If it was already at (a), there would have been no change at all made to the remote.

Your remote is named `origin`, which is the standard naming convention. So, if you add a local tracking branch for the remote `master`, it will be called `origin/master`, and it will reference the same commit after a push occurs for that branch:

```
a            <-- master (a)*  <-- origin/master (a)
 \
  b - c - d  <-- my-destinations (d)

(*) - Indicates branch that is checked out
```

Note that if you did not push while `my-destinations` was checked out, then `origin` wouldn't have your new commits b, c, and d, unless you used command-line flags or some other method to push all the branches to `origin`.  If you did push with `my-destinations` checked out, then there would also be b-c-d commits on the remote and an `origin/my-destinations` local tracking reference that would also point to (d).

But the big question is how to get your new commits back to `master`. To get your new commits to `master` from `my-destinations`, you can just `git merge my-destinations` with master checked out, which, in this case, will just "fast-forward" master up to the (d) commit, since `master` is referencing a parent of `my-destinations` (i.e. they didn't diverge - you can think of a-b-c-d as a straight line rather than a branch).  After the merge, you would have:

```
a            <-- origin/master (a)
 \
  b - c - d   <-- master (d)*  <-- my-destinations (d)
```

Then, after pushing to remote, `origin/master` will update so that it matches `master` at commit (d) - i.e. all three refs would be pointing to (d).

---

**Note:** If `master` and `my-destinations` *had* diverged, you could either merge or rebase to bring them back together.  Look up "visual git tutorial" in Google and you should run across several good tutorials that will walk you through these.

**Also note:** I recommend Git Extensions as an open-source GUI tool that will help you see exactly what is going on with your branches, commits, local and remote much more easily with a GUI.  It has helped me learn Git a lot easier, I always have it open in the background while working in Visual Studio or other tools in the foreground. It will basically show you something similar to the diagrams above for whatever repo you have open, as changes are made.