# Git: Cannot merge feature branch to the current branch

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-bash

I create a xxx branch from master and then create yyy from xxx branch. There are 2 files in xxx branch and then I add one file after creatimng the branch yyy. Now I want to apply the changes in the yyy branch to xxx branch by merge but after running the following:

```
git checkout yyy
git merge xxx
```

It gives "Already up to date." message, but I do not see the changes on branch xxx, but the changes are seen on the branch yyy. I mean that there are still 2 files in xxx and the added file is not seen.

So, my questions are:

**1.** Is there any flag, etc that I should do in order to merge these 2 branch?

**2.** Normally I use Gith Bash in order to run git commands. Is it better Git CMD? And can I use cmd instead of git command lines? I mean is there any pros or cons between them?

Comment: Did you staged and committed the changes in xxx branch before trying to merge in the second branch ?

Comment: I am not sure, because I have tried many different things. But if I had done, normally I think I would see  the thanges in xxx branch. How can I check this?

Comment: write $ git status in both branches, tell us what you see

Comment: @tawfiknasser Get "*On branch yyy. Your branch is ahead of 'origin/yyy' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits). nothing to commit, working tree clean"*.

Comment: You should merge yyy into xxx. So checkout xxx than 'git merge yyy'

Comment: @sergzemsk I tried also it before asking and encounter the following message: "merge: yyy - not something we can merge"

Comment: @Jack try to use: 'git log --all --decorate --stat' to see what's going on

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862933/how-to-resolve-gits-not-something-we-can-merge-error

Comment: @sergzemsk I encountered "*error: unknown option `all'. usage: git status [<options>] [--] <pathspec>..."*

Comment: @g_bor I am not sure, but do you mean the selected answer of that question? I am not sıre to make master branch because the example in my problem, I do not want to merge with master

Comment: @Jack my fault, 'git log --all --decorate --stat --graph'

Comment: @sergzemsk It displays the branches, but how can I use it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have the things the other way around. You want to merge yyy to xxx, so you should do:

```
git checkout xxx
git merge yyy
```

Git is right in saying that yyy is up to date, when you try to merge xxx, as yyy is based on xxx.

You can have a look at this tutorial:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: I tried also it before asking and encounter the following message: "*merge: yyy - not something we can merge*"

Answer (score 1):

I think you have your branches backwards in your commands.

#### According to [this git cheatsheet](https://training.github.com/downloads/github-git-cheat-sheet/)

`$ git checkout [branch-name]`

- Switches to the specified branch and updates the working directory

`$ git merge [branch]`

- Combines the **specified** branch’s history into the **current branch**...

#### For your case:

If branch `yyy` has changes and you want to merge changes into branch `xxx`:

```
$ git checkout xxx    --Checkout branch to update
$ git merge yyy       --Merge yyy changes into current branch
```

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and @g_bor's answer that I had already said not worked?

Comment: Have you committed the changes to branch `yyy` before attempting to merge?

Comment: I think I missed push command that caused the problem. Thansk a lot for your helps, voted up ;)