# git pull always returns "not something we can merge"

Tags: macos, git, github, merge, homebrew

No matter what repository I am in I get this response from `git pull` "`merge: 012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012 - not something we can merge`". I have tried uninstalling git and re-installing with no luck. `git fetch origin` and `git merge origin/master` work fine. I could very well use those commands instead of `git pull` but Homebrew uses `git pull` and now it is broken too.

[UPDATE] This apparently was related to `pyenv`. Once I removed that from my PATH then everything went back to normal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does "not something we can merge" arise?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388625/how-does-not-something-we-can-merge-arise)

Comment: Please do `git remote -v` and what is this merge: thing you're adding at the end of git pull ?

Comment: What's in `.git/FETCH_HEAD` at this point?  The `pull` script writes stuff in that file, in a historic (but kind of botched) attempt to make `git fetch` and `git merge` work without needing "remote tracking branches".

Comment: @MichaelDurrant The "merge" is not part of `git pull` that is the message I get when I do a pull.

Comment: @JoseMagana I would say no. This happens to all repositories, the message is different, and the SHA is not really a SHA.

Comment: Someone just ran into this again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27592779/git-pull-always-fails-but-git-fetch-merge-are-fine