# git pull always fails, but git fetch/merge are fine

Tags: macos, git, git-merge, git-pull

When I `git pull` in any repository, I always get the following merge error:

```
aetherboard:shwangster shwangster$ git pull -v
From github.com:sirspinach/shwangster
 = [up to date]      master     -> origin/master
merge: 012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012 - not
something we can merge
```

On the other hand, `git fetch` and `git merge origin/master` work like a charm. So I've been able to work around this problem for a while. However, I needed to update brew today, and the same error prevents me from doing that.

Here is the output from `brew update`, which shows git again attempting to merge with the mysterious `0120120120120...`.

```
aetherboard:gitrepos shwangster$ brew update
merge: 012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012012 - not 
something we can merge
Error: Failure while executing: git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's wrong, but take a look at the contents of the file `FETCH_HEAD` (in the `.git` directory) after a failed `git pull`.  The `pull` command runs `fetch` with extra arguments that tell it to leave traces in `FETCH_HEAD`, and then uses those traces to run `git merge`.  There's something goofy with those traces, causing the `pull` script to issue a faulty `merge` command.

Comment: Thanks for your help, torek. Here's the contents of `FETCH_HEAD` from two different repositories after I attempted git pull:
    1. `ecbacbe7d1b15058065d8856328cecba8141b1d0  branch 'master' of github.com:sirspinach/shwangster`

    2. `206b62d28091d98909947ad32085a15fa463d7f5 not-for-merge branch 'master' of github.com:sirspinach/cs61a-scheme`

Comment: Exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271075/git-pull-always-returns-not-something-we-can-merge

Comment: Interesting... the file contents are sane, the problem must be in the choice of merge head.  Looks like `tr '\012' ' '` has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a clue in the other (pretty much exact duplicate) question that Kaz noted in a comment, that the problem went away when `pyenv` was taken out of `$PATH`.

Here's the bit from the pull script that takes the `FETCH_HEAD` trace and turns it into an argument to `git merge` (or to `git rebase` when doing a rebasing pull):

```
merge_head=$(sed -e '/  not-for-merge   /d' \
        -e 's/  .*//' "$GIT_DIR"/FETCH_HEAD | \
        tr '\012' ' ')
```

(By the way, note that those are tabs before and after `not-for-merge` and in the second `-e` argument to sed.  Cut-and-paste generally turns tabs into spaces, and did here.)

I imagine the `sed` part is working correctly and the failure occurs with the `tr` invocation.  In fact, it looks like whatever `tr` is being used, is simply spitting out the `012` string (for a total of 60 characters, or 20 instances of the three-character group—not sure how that happens given that the `sed` output is, or should be, a 40-character SHA-1).

If your shell is `sh` or `bash`, see what:

```
$ type tr
```

prints.  If you use a csh variant, `which tr` will show you what it will run.  (I'm not sure off-hand what to use for dash and zsh.)  If you get something other than `/usr/bin/tr`, that may explain the problem.  (If you do get `/usr/bin/tr` see what `type sed` or `which sed` says: these should be `/usr/bin/sed`.)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It turned out that the `tr` that git had been expecting was replaced by [something else](https://github.com/itsnauman/termrule) that I installed a long time ago.